# How to get random access to a stream returned by an Android SAF framework on the external drive?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-external-storage, random-access, storage-access-framework

I have a large file on a extended drive (or USB drive) to open directly from there and it is around 1GB so I can't use BufferedStream. Is it possible to gain a random access to this stream which is returned by SAF ( Android Storage Access Framework)?
Please note that I want to write some bytes in the middle of the stream.

I have already written the following, Have I done something wrong or it is not possible anyway.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1){
            Uri uri = data.getData();

                InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                //stream does not have a random access!

        }
    }
```

I am using Android API Level 21 (Lollipop)